# Detecting where to start replay of messages when some messages might have been lost due to a disaster

Tags: algorithm, disaster-recovery

I have a publisher application that sends messages to multiple subscribers. Each message is assigned an increasing sequence number. Lets say A, B and C are three subscribers and Publisher has sent message number 1 to A, 2,3,4,7 to B and 5,6 to C.

Whether message number x will go to A,B or C subscriber is a function of some immutable attribute of message (not the number) i.e message number 7 is routed to B because it may be relating to a stock whose symbol starts with 'b'.

The publisher has a map with maximum sequence number sent to each subscriber. The map at present will look like:

```
{"A" -> 1, "B" ->7, "C" ->6}
```

At this point we don't know whether these messages are successfully delivered to respective subscribers. However it is guranteed that messages will be delivered in sequence.

If we have a disaster that required rebooting the publisher, we need to replay messages that might have been lost to subscriber.

**Important:** in order to replay messages to subscribers, the publisher needs to send replay request to another upstream server and it does not have persistent store of all messages it has previously seen. So the publisher here acts more like a router. There is a cost to replay messages from upstream server so I want to minimize how many messages I need to ask for replay.

Current algorithm I use is to find the maximum message sequence that each subscriber has received. Say we get back something like:

```
{"A"->1, "B" ->7, "C" ->6}
```

Current algorithm just assumes that we need to replay from minimum message number recovered from subscribers (1 in this case). Whereas actually we need to worry about messages with number greater than 7 only in this case.

I can periodically save the map of sent highest message numbers for each subscriber on publisher side.

So I could save the state of this map every 5 minutes. If after restart I see that all subscribers have received message number above the last saved value, I can replay from maximum of recovered sequence numbers (7 in this case). That reduces the number of messages to replay.

I think there might be a standard algorithm for this problem, but web search did not yield anything useful. If someone can point me to relevant algorithm that would be very useful.

Please assume that:

- Saving each message number sent to each subscriber is not an option.
- The subscriber can handle duplicate messages well so we want to err on side of replaying more than required messages.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but if each subscriber has a separate channel over which it receives messages, shouldn't each channel be handled separately?

Comment: Why don't you keep the last sent message number per subscriber since the subscribers seem to be independent in your case (they can all receive totally different messages)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Paul - Yes subscribers are independent. Lets say subscriber A had seen message number 5, so we just need to figure out from publisher's current state whether it was supposed to send anything higher than 5 and then only send those messages. The issue here is that publisher does not have these message in cache (it has to request them from another external FIX server). So the idea here is to minimize how much we request for replay. Sorry for not clarifying this earlier.

Comment: Why don't you keep the last sent message number per subscriber since the subscribers seem to be independent in your case ----- yes they are independent and indeed I am trying to keep last sent message per subscriber, the problem is to determine where to start replaying given this state. Basically assume that publisher is restarted abruptly so the value of last-sent messages it has saved in persistent store may not be up-to-date. It will be costly to update this state for every message send.

Comment: Ok then you have two cases: 1. the subscribers are totally independent and in that case you cannot minimize the requests since you will need to request all different messages; 2. the subscribers are not totally independent and in that case sometimes one message will need to be resent to multiple subscribers.
In case 2 you need to find the common messages to resent towards the subscribers and keep them until they are not useful anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this needs a specific algorithm, but what you have is a specific use-case. I have seen similar use-cases in Kafka and there would be a separate setting for each use-case. The answer to your question boils down to the question that how are the messages read by the subscribers.

Are all the subscribers updating the same DB(or performing the same action) once they receive an update? In that case, you can send the latest message(`7`) to one of the subscribers.

Or is each subscriber performing its own action upon receiving a message? You then need to replay the latest message of each subscriber.`{"A"->1, "B" ->7, "C" ->6}`

Comment: Each subscriber will handle messages in same manner, but we have a partitioning logic for deciding where a message should go, for example all messages relating to stocks whose name starts with A will go to say 'A' subscriber. We can determine that message 7 belongs to subscriber B but to do that we need to request replay of message number 7 onwards from upstream server. I am looking for way to minimize the replay requests, I can make some ad-hoc optimizations but thought there might be a pattern or algorithm around similar problems.

Comment: I don't think you have any other option other than persisting that data @AmolRegmi. Have a single record for each subscriber or a single row for the entire subscribers' list telling the current message delivered to each subscriber(based on your use case choose one of the above methods). And persist that message after you receive a 200 message when you call a subscriber. In case of a restart, read the message from the DB and send all the updates from the message id in the DB till the latest message id.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that It is an architectural problem and not an algorithmic problem.

Comment: You only need to find the last message id(or the maximum value of the id among the message Ids) that you last sent. And replay from that message id. Ain't that true? Persist the latest message id in the DB which is read by subscriber.